# libsvm returning a trivial solution

Tags: machine-learning, classification, libsvm, svm

I'm trying to use [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) to classify data as seen in the following picture: 
[image: scatter plot for SVM]

You can see "by eye" there is a soft separation between blue and red, but some blue samples exists throughout the entire area I would say "should be tagged red".

I can't get libsvm to return a meaningful classification and keep getting the trivial one- all dots tagged blue. This happens with various kernels and parameter values. I think playing with the cost variable don't solve this, because there are 10-fold more blue samples than red ones.

Am I missing something? Is there some libsvm parameter which handle this case?
Or maybe SVM is inappropriate for the task and you can suggest something which is?

Comment: No offense, but all dots are black.

Comment: Please post what kernel/parameter values you've tried.  The dots show all black for me as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)
I've tried the following params: 
'-t 0 -c 4 -v 3', '-t 1 -n 0.9 -v 3', '-t 2 -d 4 -v 3', '-t 3 -g 1 -v 3', '-t 0 -c 0.1 -v 3', '-t 0 -c 10 -v 3'

Comment: You need to try more values for C and kernel parameters, in an automated grid search. There's not a great way to know a priori which will do well, and you need to try lots. I've had success in the past checking sigma values of `2 ^ (-4, -2, 0, 2, ..., 10)` and C of `2^ (-9, -6, ..., 18)`.

Comment: I agree with Dougal - vary the parameters in orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to get a non trivial solution with a linear SVM.
You should try different values of C and also, as your data is unbalanced, use the wi parameter to fix the weight of each class.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing some Principal Component Analysis or some Independent Component Analysis as pre-processing. This should help you out. There are plenty of examples with the iris data base out there.